Errror 500 on multiple pages (node/add/page and admin/config/people/accounts)
I have a fresh install of Drupal 8, and I can't use the pages that are critical for the operation of Drupal.

node/add/page - fairly critical if I can't add a page
admin/config/people/accounts - not AS critical but would be nice to have working

I suspect both pages are the same issue. When reading my nginx error log I see:
2024/11/09 08:36:43 [error] 1475812#1475812: *2614 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /var/www/html/wiki.catspeed.cc/vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/SandboxExtension.php on line 130; PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0; PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0; PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0" while reading response header from upstream, client: 104.158.9.179, server: wiki.catspeed.cc, request: "GET /node/add/page HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock:", host: "wiki.catspeed.cc", referrer: "https://wiki.catspeed.cc/node/add"

I did some googling and people suggested increasing PHP memory limit. I already had the default 128M and I tried 512M and 1024M and 10240M and 20480M. The lower numbers give the same error in the error log, and if I increase it to 10240M or higher, when I load the pages, it crashes my entire nginx and brings entire server down.
I also tried increasing maximum execution time and it does not work either.
Both settings were confirmed on the status page.
Why doesn't increasing the memory limit work? It is obviously a memory issue...
setting max memory to 1024M, etc.
setting max execution time to 600s etc.
